# Tab indicator not sliding when controller is added

Tags: flutter, tabs

I added a Tab in my app

My code looks like:

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("ADD ITEM"),
      bottom: TabBar(
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        tabs: [
          Tab(text: "Main Product"),
          Tab(text: "Unit Groups"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _tabController,
      children: [Container(), UnitGroupsList()],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I initiated controller like:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
   _tabController = new TabController(
   length: 2,
   vsync: this,
 );
 super.initState();
```

}

However, when I set controller to this TabBarView and when I swipe to change tab, the indicator of tab does not slide.

And when I manually click on another tab, only indicator is moved

Required:
[image: Tab1]

[image: Tab2]

What I get:

When I swiped, I moved to next tab, but indicator is still at 1st tab:
[image: When i swiped i moved to next tab but indicator is still at 1st tab]

Comment: remove controller

Comment: actually yes , removing controller works. but i need controller to navigate to another tabs on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1);
```

This did the job, I didn't have to assign controller to navigate between tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Put the same _tabController in both TabBar and TabBarView

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
       
        tabs: [
         ...
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: [...],
    ),
  ),
);
```